# How to delete first page from muliple PDF's

Tags: pdf

I have a collection of PDF's that sometimes have a info page for the first page of the document that I want to remove.

If there a quick way to delete this info page from all of my pdf's or at least a way to show all pdf's that have more than one page so I can better find the ones that need to be fixed?

Do you know of any program that can do this? Or way to do this with python?

Note: The info page has text on it that that always remains the same "LAND TITLE OFFICE"

Using Windows 7 OS

Thanks

Some Research turned up the following:

http://www.python.org/workshops/2002-02/papers/17/index.htm

[http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html](http://www.unixuser.org/%7Eeuske/python/pdfminer/index.html)

https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try these two ways:

- [PdfTK](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/install-pdftk/) is an utility to manipulate PDFs. Check this [link](http://commonsenseatheism.com/?p=8335), they are doing something similar to what you need (in the comments someone also posted a script for windows)
- [PDFsam](http://www.pdfsam.org) is a graphical powerful tool to manipulate PDFs in bulk. The split+merge sections should do the trick.

Both of them are free, I'd suggest to study the first if you want to write a "recipe" that you can use often, but the later if you have to do it once.

Comment: Otherwise if you want to migrate to Linux give me a call and I'll suggest you something better!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the opensource PDFBox as a command line utility to split PDF's.

The link for PDFBox is here: [link](http://pdfbox.apache.org/index.html)

The documentation for splitting a PDF using PDFBox is here: [link](http://pdfbox.apache.org/commandlineutilities/PDFSplit.html)

You could use the PDFBox extract text functionality from a batch script and combine with grep to identify pages that contain the text you are looking for.  The extract text documentation is here: [link](http://pdfbox.apache.org/commandlineutilities/ExtractText.html)