# Display contents of docx file in android activity

Tags: java, android, image, docx

I have a docx file inside my android app. 
I want to view its contents on an activity , page wise.

say, I want to view page no 2, i want something like

```
display(DOCX_NAME,2);
```

also, on display, there should not be any re-formatting(I want the docx page to be displayed as if a snapshot was taken of it)

how do i go about it? 
also, its a 200 page docx, and I will use the display part quite a few times during runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They is no concept of a page in the docx format: The pages completely depend on the implementation of the wordviewer.

However, JasonPluText has created a demo showing [AndroidDocxToHTML](https://github.com/plutext/AndroidDocxToHtml)

See this question for more details: [how to Show or Read docx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447865/how-to-show-or-read-docx-file)

Comment: do you know of any similar format that does have pages? 
i want the contents of each page to be displayed when i want it to. 
will pdf work? 
if yes, then which library is good for reading and displaying on android?

Comment: Yes, I think PDF can do that. Have a look at this link: http://commonsenseatheism.com/?p=8335 and this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019447/how-to-delete-first-page-from-muliple-pdfs , they are giving infos about manipulating pages in PDF

Comment: also, i have a lot of symbols in my docx. 
how do i convert it to docx whilst retaining the small size?

Comment: I dont understand your question. Could you maybe create a new question ?

Comment: i dont really know how to frame it. 
i have a 500 page chemistry-related book(with all symbols etc) which has questions.
i want each of these questions to be on a separate page. 
how do i do that?

Comment: It's quite difficult to help you with so less information. A new question would help a lot

Comment: can i ask about it on chat ?

Comment: I think it would be a bit too complicated to explain: Just create a new question

Comment: just one more thing;
which library should i use to convert a particular PDF page to image?

Comment: see this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332791/converting-pdf-to-image-with-proper-formatting